# EOF when reading a line error in a python script

Tags: python, eof

I see this error message posted all over this website, but I've not been able to resolve my issue with these threads. When I run a python script, I get the following traceback:

```
File "raxml_bootstrapped_genetrees.py", line 147, in main
correct_jobs = raw_input(question.format(args.cores, jobs, args.threads))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

When I go to the relevant part of the script, around line 147:

```
138 def main():
139    args = get_args()
140    # get the number of jobs as available_procs / threads for raxml
141    jobs = args.cores / args.threads
142    question = "The total number of cores in use is {0}. This will run \n" + \
143        "{1} concurrent jobs of {2} thread(s). Is this correct [Y/n]? "
144    if args.quiet:
145        correct_jobs = "Y"
146    else:
147        correct_jobs = raw_input(question.format(args.cores, jobs, args.threads))
148    if correct_jobs == "Y":
149        assert jobs < multiprocessing.cpu_count(), "The total number of jobs * threads is greather than the available CPUs"
150        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(jobs)
151        # read through previous best trees to get seed values for -p
152        raxml_call_regex = re.compile("\n\nRAxML was called as follows:\n\n(.*)\n\n")
153        seeds = {}
154        all_tree_directories = glob.glob(os.path.join(args.best_trees, '*'))
```

`get_args()` are the following:

```
def get_args():
    """Get arguments from CLI"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description="""Program description""")
    parser.add_argument(
            "--input",
            required=True,
            type=is_dir,
            action=FullPaths,
            help="""The input directory containing alignments in phylip format"""
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--best-trees",
            required=True,
            type=is_dir,
            action=FullPaths,
            help="""The directory containing the best trees"""
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--output",
            required=True,
            action=CreateDir,
            help="""The output directory to hold alignments"""
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--bootreps",
            type=int,
            default=100,
            help="""The number of bootstrap replicates to run"""
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--outgroup",
            type=str,
            help="""The outgroup to use"""
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--threads",
            type=int,
            default=1,
            help="""The number of RAxML threads to run (best to determine empirically)"""
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--cores",
            type=int,
            default=1,
            help="""The number of concurrent RAxML jobs to run"""
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--quiet",
            action="store_true",
            default=False,
            help="""Suppress the CPU usage question""",
        )
    return parser.parse_args()
```

I have tried changing `raw_input` to `input`, but the error message is replicated. I have tried commenting out from `jobs = args.core / args.threads`. I honestly don't know what to do or what the issue is. By default, the `--cores` and `--threads` arguments are set to 1 if not specified in command.

Comment: Please post [mcve].

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: I think that's unnecessarily harsh. At the very least, maybe give some direction on what additional code to post if you think you know better. Were I new to a language, and had little idea what constituted MCV, this would be incredibly off-putting.

Comment: there does not seem to be a problem with this part of the code. At least i do not see one. Whats in the ``get_args()``? Is line 147 the ``args = get_args()``?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to replicate this given this is a script within a much larger utility package called phyluce, which calls upon other types of bioinformatic and phylogenetic programs. My understanding of EOF errors are typically syntax issues, are they not? But, as @Vervious says, I'm new to scripting.

Comment: The argument referenced is --threads. However, this argument is optional and if not stated (as I have done), it is defaulted at 1. Line 147 is `args.threads)`, which is the next to last line I provided.

Comment: @MikeF And to answer your question, __no__ you do not need a coma. In fact it would be an error.

Comment: @ Ev. Kounis thanks

Comment: You know in which line the error is, copy the important part, and replace calls to unrelated stuff with example data.

Comment: Don't add more code, just remove interactions with it, if it's not revelant.

Comment: @MikeF Try changing the ``raw_input`` to ``input``

Comment: Oh, it's EOF error. It means that you called `raw_input`, but there was nothing more to read.

Comment: From the ``raw_input()`` documentation: __If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised__

Comment: Ok, what arguments you're calling it with?

Comment: But I do not call args.cores or args.threads in my script. These are optional arguments. If not called, default is 1. So my understanding is args.quiet (whatever that is) should be used by the program.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus `phyluce_genetrees_run_raxml_bootstraps --input mafft-phylip --best-trees best_trees --output raxml_bootstrapped_genetrees --bootreps 500 --outgroup Ptilopachus_petrosus_FMNH_B45101_T
`

Comment: @Mike: I can't reproduce it. It looks like it works for me. Is `phyluce_genetrees_run_raxml_bootstraps` name of your program?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus It is a subprogram within phyluce. I run this off a cluster, so I `module load phyluce` and then call this subprogram with `phyluce_genetrees_run_raxml_bootstraps`. There is more to the script than what I provided.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis: changing `raw_input` to `input` did not fix my issue